# Angular2+ Routing - Content Download while navigating

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I'm implementing a pretty identical routing for 2 routing modules.

The components are properly rendered for both the routing module, the problem is that for "not working" routing,
if I navigate by clicking on the paths it seems that the page reloads... In console I see that the browser downloads again the js files ( bundle / polyfil etc.. )

## StartRoutingModule - not working

```
import { OrderCreateComponent } from '../order-create/order-create.component';
import { StarterComponent } from './../starter.component';
import { NgModule, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AdminDashboard1Component } from "../../admin/admin-dashboard1/admin-dashboard1.component";

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: 'app',
        component: StarterComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            component: AdminDashboard1Component            
          },
          {
            path: 'OrderCreate',
            component: OrderCreateComponent
          }
        ]
      }
    ])
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class StarterRoutingModule { }
```

## AdminRoutingModule - working

```
import { AdminDashboard2Component } from './../admin-dashboard2/admin-dashboard2.component';
import { AdminDashboard1Component } from './../admin-dashboard1/admin-dashboard1.component';
import { AdminComponent } from './../admin.component';
import { NgModule, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: 'admin',
        component: AdminComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            redirectTo: 'dashboard1',
            pathMatch: 'full'
          },
          {
            path: 'dashboard1',
            component: AdminDashboard1Component
          },
          {
            path: 'dashboard2',
            component: AdminDashboard2Component
          }
        ]
      }
    ])
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class AdminRoutingModule { }
```

## app-routing-module.ts

```
import { StarterComponent } from './../starter/starter.component';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { StarterRoutingModule } from "../starter/starter-routing/starter-routing.module";
import { AdminRoutingModule } from "../admin/admin-routing/admin-routing.module";


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AdminRoutingModule ,
    StarterRoutingModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
//      { path: '', redirectTo: 'starter2', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'starter', component: StarterComponent }  
    ])
  ],
  declarations: [],
  exports: [ RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

With these paths the browser download again js/image etc... ( seems to reload)

```
/app/
/app/OrderCreate
```

With these paths the application just load the properly component without downloading again js/other contents.

```
/admin/dashboard1
/admin/dashboard2
```

Where is the error?
Thanks to support

Comment: Have you list AdminModule in your app-routing.module.ts file?

Comment: Hi Anoop, no, I added it to the code but the results is the same. I have integrated the code in the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may convert your app-routing.module.ts file like this

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { LoadChildren, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
                          {
                              path: '',
                              loadChildren: './starter/starter.module#StarterModule
                          },
                          {
                              path: 'admin',
                              loadChildren: './admin/admin.module#AdminModule
                          },];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Angular project follows a tree structure. So its good to declare related tasks under a same module (like components Dashboard1, and Dashboard2 in AdminModule) and specify routing in its routing.module file.

Suppose you have no module for a functionality(say a single view as home page). You can define such components in your app.module.ts file and specify its routing in app-routing.module.ts file after importing that component there something like:

```
{ path: 'starter', component: StarterComponent }
```

If you are using the attribute redirectTo, the specified route should be predefined. In your code:

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'starter2', pathMatch: 'full' }
```

But you don't mention what to do if a url starter2 is found.

If you check these with your code, I'm sure you can fix your issue soon.

Comment: So you suggest to keep the routing in a single place in app-routing.module.ts as best practice right ?

Comment: Not exactly brother. You need to organize related components inside a single module. For example if a message related task is there, so you need a MessageModule( where you can declare SentMessage, ViewMessageList, and individualMessage like components) and a MessageRoutingModule (contains routing to these components).

Comment: Then you can specify MessageModule using loadChildren attribute in AppRoutingModule. Which allow you to create routes like message/sent, message/list, message/view etc.

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was on how I implemented the links while testing the routing:

not working way:

```
<a href="/app/OrderCreate">OrderCreate</a>
```

working way:

```
<a routerLink="/app/OrderCreate">OrderCreate</a>
```

With **routerLink** attribute all is loading properly without page reoloading